# Android Searchview disabling fullscreen not working after selecting suggestion

Tags: android, searchview, landscape-portrait, android-fullscreen

**Situation**

I have a SearchView in my toolbar that displays suggestions to the user when they enter in a search. Initially, in landscape orientation, everything works fine with the softkeyboard displayed and the searchview visible. However, after the user selects a suggestion and tries to do a second search, the search interface is now in fullscreen where the searchview is covered up and suggestions can not be seen.

**Problem**

How do I get no full screen consistently no matter how many times the search function is used?

**Things I have tried**

ImeOptions - flagNoFullscreen, flagNoExtractUi

**Code**

MainFragment

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.favorites, menu);

    MenuItem toggleItem = menu.findItem(R.id.toggle_shake);
    setUpToggleShake(toggleItem);

    MenuItem singleSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_restaurant);
    setUpSingleSearch(menu, singleSearchItem);
}

private void setUpSingleSearch(final Menu menu, final MenuItem singleSearchItem) {
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(singleSearchItem);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search Restaurant");
    searchView.setMaxWidth(10000);
    searchView.setImeOptions(searchView.getImeOptions() | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN |
        EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            displaySuggestions(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
            MatrixCursor cursor = (MatrixCursor)(searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter()
                    .getCursor());
            if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                String restaurantId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                        RestaurantTable.Cols.ID));
                mFavoritesRestaurantListAdapter.setSingleSearchRestaurant(restaurantId);
                mFavoritesRestaurantListAdapter.onSingleSearch();
            }
            searchView.clearFocus();
            searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
            setItemsVisibility(menu, singleSearchItem, true);

            return false;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setItemsVisibility(menu, singleSearchItem, false);
            searchView.setFocusable(true);
            searchView.requestFocus();
            searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            setItemsVisibility(menu, singleSearchItem, true);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }
    });
    final AutoCompleteTextView searchAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView
            .findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify. You press search -> search bar is expanded -> you type query -> you select suggested item -> search bar is collapsed and keyboard is gone -> you press search once again -> you see large white text box on top and keyboard on bottom. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that's the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the call to SearchView's onActionViewCollapsed. I did a workaround by adding collapseActionView in menu.xml.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_restaurant"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
```

Then remove searchview.onActionViewCollapsed. Add menuItem.collapseActionView instead.

```
searchView.clearFocus();
//searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
menuItem.collapseActionView(); //Added this
setItemsVisibility(menu, singleSearchItem, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep things simple. I mean, why do you use all that `requestFocus`, `clearFocus` etc. I've just created a very basic implementation of your task and everything works like a charm. Check it out:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView selectedValueTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);
        selectedValueTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_with_search, menu);
        final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                null,
                new String[]{"value"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        ));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, "value"});
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    cursor.addRow(new Object[]{i, query + i});
                }
                searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().changeCursor(cursor);
                return true;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getItem(position);
                selectedValueTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("value")));
                // do this last because collapseActionView calls onQueryTextChange("")
                // which changes cursor data
                searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;

    }
}
```